# costmap_2d local into image

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I was wondering if there is already a function to convert the costmap_2d data into a image (or other kind of matrix, so that it is easier to search through).

I have managed to subscribe to the local costmap_2d and wanted to check particular areas by myself now. Unfortunately the format that I receive the costmap in is not very intuitive (at least for me). I was wondering if there is a simple conversion. If not, where can I find the convention on how the information is stored (columns, rows, height, width)?

[here](http://answers.ros.org/question/147846/how-costmap-works/) I saw it must be possible, just that I don t know how.

I am running ros hydro

Kind regards,
Marcus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203708/costmap_2d-local-into-image/) by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BP](https://answers.ros.org/users/10951/bp/) on 2015-03-01**:
You asked in my question to help u- I can give you the code (it basically uses openCV, hope it will help)
http://pastebin.com/cspN42jv
It is not a fully answer so i post it in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use the [saveMap](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1Costmap2D.html#a04cd3558a672159a3ad1b151b1d19661) method from costmap_2D

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0